# How to use expressions instead of fields in exportService, Grails?

Tags: grails, replace, expression, field

I am trying to do something like this:

```
if( params?.format && params.format != "html" ) {

        def extension = params.format == 'excel' ? 'xls' : params.format
        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=programs.${extension}")

        List fields = [
                "id",
                "${field1.customFunction('property')}", //<- the part here
                ...
        ]
        Map labels = [:]
        Map formatters = [:]
        Map parameters = [:]

        exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, hhList, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
```

So basically, I am trying to get some returned value of a function, not a field. How to do that?

Comment: You don't modify the fields to contain expressions like that. You need to modify the collection to contain the correct information instead. E.g. whatever you have in `ffList` is in the format you want. Remember `ffList` can be just a `List` of `Map`s so you have a lot of flexibility as to what data you provide to the plugin.

Comment: Alternatively using `formatters` may work, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Oh, so any property of the object in the list.. that sounds like the answer. I don't know much about formatters though. I'll read more on that. Ty